# await inside a for loop in a lambda in node.js

Tags: node.js, for-loop, lambda, async-await

Running a lambda in AWS with node.js.   I had a for loop (was forEach but changed it) that iterrates through an array domain names, then a forEach that loops through a number of file names in s3, appends it to the domain, and sends to another function (not shown) for URL signing.  I would like to put a file in S3 for each domain name, but it's not working.  I didn't use forEach for the first loop so i thought it would.  I can only successfully upload to s3 if i post one big file by calling it after the following code:

```
for (const base of mybaseUrl) {
//  mybaseUrl.forEach(base => {
    console.log('working on ' + base);
    uriList.forEach(uri => {
          let hostPlanCode = uri.substring(9, 12);
          let networkID = uri.substring(13, 16);
          let geoCode = base.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
          let mappedGeoCode = (geoMap[geoCode]);
          console.log(hostPlanCode);
          console.log(networkID);
          console.log(mappedGeoCode);
          let newUrl = (base + uri);
          
          signUrl(newUrl,secretKey,hostPlanCode,networkID,mappedGeoCode);
    });
    console.log('finished up ' + base);
     let geoCode = base.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
     let mappedGeoCode = (geoMap[geoCode]);
     const upload = await s3.upload({
        Body: signedList.join('\n\n'),
        Bucket: s3UrlListBucket,
        Key: mappedGeoCode + fileUploadName 
    }).promise();

  };
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how long your code takes to run but there are time constraints on AWS lambdas (or any hosting for serverless functions). This could the reason for failure.

In any case, it's usually bad practice to have an `await` inside of a for loop because it prevents parallelism: each iteration of the loop waits for the previous one to complete before being triggered. A better pattern is to run all iterations in parallel and await their completion at the end.

You could try something like:

```
const uploads = [];
for (const base of mybaseUrl) {
    /* rest of the code... */
    uploads.push(s3.upload({
        Body: signedList.join('\n\n'),
        Bucket: s3UrlListBucket,
        Key: mappedGeoCode + fileUploadName 
    }).promise());
};
await Promise.all(uploads);
```

You should also be able to use the `forEach` loop the same way, or even better, use `Array.map`:

```
await Promise.all(mybaseUrl.map((base) => {
    /* rest of the code... */
    return s3.upload({
        Body: signedList.join('\n\n'),
        Bucket: s3UrlListBucket,
        Key: mappedGeoCode + fileUploadName 
    }).promise();
}));
```