# AWS SQS send message in a loop by AWS Lambda NodeJs 18 (aws-sdk V3)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, async-await

I looking for a exemple of AWS SQS send message in a loop by AWS Lambda NodeJs 18 (so aws-sdk V3).

```
exports.handler = async function (event) {
    const mydatas = JSON.parse(event.body);
    /* ..... */

    const sqsClient = new SQSClient({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });

    await mydatas.forEach(async mydata => {
        const command = new SendMessageCommand({
            DelaySeconds: 10,
            MessageAttributes: {
                'x': {
                    DataType: 'Number',
                    StringValue: `${mydata.a}`
                },
                'y': {
                    DataType: 'Number',
                    StringValue: `${mydata.b}`
                },
                'z': {
                    DataType: 'Number',
                    StringValue: `${mydata.c}`
                }
            },
            MessageBody: 'My_message',
            QueueUrl: process.env.MY_SQS_URL
        });

        await sqsClient.send(command)
            .then((data) => console.log(data))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
       body: "OK",
    };

};
```

My problem is `await sqsClient.send(command)` never execute.

I see [await inside a for loop in a lambda in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72132009/await-inside-a-for-loop-in-a-lambda-in-node-js) And I think use `Promise.all` but `send` is not a function.

```
await Promise.all(mybaseUrl.map((base) => {
    /* rest of the code... */
    return sqsClient.send(command).promise();
}));
```

**EDIT**

is it a sample without loop: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_sqs_code_examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use juste `Promise.all...` and no `.promise()` after `sqsClient.send(command)`

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
'use strict';

const { SQSClient, SendMessageCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-sqs');

exports.handler = async function (event) {
    const mydatas = JSON.parse(event.body);
    

    const sqsClient = new SQSClient({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });

    await Promise.all(mydatas.map(async (mydata) => {
        const command = new SendMessageCommand({
            DelaySeconds: 10,
            MessageAttributes: {
                'x': {
                    DataType: 'Number',
                    StringValue: `${mydata.a}`
                },
                'y': {
                    DataType: 'Number',
                    StringValue: `${mydata.b}`
                },
                'z': {
                    DataType: 'Number',
                    StringValue: `${mydata.c}`
                }
            },
            MessageBody: 'My_message',
            QueueUrl: process.env.MY_SQS_URL
        });

        const contents = await sqsClient.send(command);
        console.log(contents);
    }));

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
       body: "OK",
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer Stéphane GRILLON is correct. To clarify, your problem is that you are using `.forEach`, which doesn't support the async/await syntax. Instead, you can use `.map` and `await Promise.all` on the results of the map.

```js
exports.handler = async function (event) {
    const mydatas = JSON.parse(event.body);
    /* ..... */

    const sqsClient = new SQSClient({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });

    await Promise.all(mydatas.map(async mydata => {
        const command = new SendMessageCommand({
            DelaySeconds: 10,
            MessageAttributes: {
                'x': {
                    DataType: 'Number',
                    StringValue: `${mydata.a}`
                },
                'y': {
                    DataType: 'Number',
                    StringValue: `${mydata.b}`
                },
                'z': {
                    DataType: 'Number',
                    StringValue: `${mydata.c}`
                }
            },
            MessageBody: 'My_message',
            QueueUrl: process.env.MY_SQS_URL
        });

        await sqsClient.send(command)
            .then((data) => console.log(data))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }));

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
       body: "OK",
    };

};
```